# Custom Grid Date filter format problem on search

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento-2.0

I'm trying to format the display and also the datepicker value when selecting the date in Filter for my custom grid. Now the display works fine the only problem is when I filter it, it doesn't work as expected. Example I selecte a date from Feb 18, 2021 to March 17, 2021. Now in the filter it works great as it's displaying as 18/02/2021 and 17/03/2021. But the result is different. It seems Magento is interpreting in as 02/18/2021 and 03/17/2021 hence the result is wrong. Now I have this in my xml

```
<column name="date_paid" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
      <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">d/MM/Y</item>
    </item>
  </argument>
  <settings>
        <label translate="true">Date Paid</label>              
        <sortable>false</sortable>
        <draggable>false</draggable>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>        
  </settings>
</column>
```

And I also tried this

```
<column name="date_paid" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
    </item>
  </argument>
  <settings>
        <label translate="true">Date Paid</label>              
        <sortable>false</sortable>
        <draggable>false</draggable>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>
        <dateFormat>d/MM/Y</dateFormat>            
  </settings>
</column>
```

But all of this is producing a wrong result. Now when I try to remove the parameter `dateFormat` the result is correct.

How do I tell Magento to only format the display but the way it submit should be like the default? I was thinking that will be the only way to achieve what I want. I just want it to display in a `d/MM/Y` format

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<dateFormat>d/MMM/YYYY</dateFormat>` instead of `<dateFormat>d/MM/Y</dateFormat>`
for more details check [date.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/date.js) this file.